# Перегрузка оператора [ ]

Tags: c++

Не совсем понимаю, как работает перегруженный оператор `[]` в следующем коде:

```
class safearray
    {
    private:
        int arr[LIMIT];
    public:
        int& operator[](int n)
        {
            if (n < 0 || n >= LIMIT)
            {
                cout << "\nОшибочный индекс!"; exit(1);
            }
            return arr[n];
        }
    };

int main()
{
    safearay sa1;
    for (int j = 0; j < LIMIT; j++)
        sa1[j] = j * 10;
    for (j = 0; j < LIMIT; j++)
    {
        int temp = sa1[j];
        cout << "Элемент " << j << " равен " << temp << endl;
    }
    return 0;
```

Comment: Что именно вам не понятно?

Comment: @AnT `j` из строчки `sa1[j] = j * 10` передаётся как аргумент `n` в функцию `int& operator[](int n)` ?

Comment: @AnT т.е. в данном случае строчка `sa1[j] = j * 10` эквивалентна строчке `arr[j] = j * 10` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Во первых вы в `main()` обезопасили в цикле for выход за предела границ, так что там не будет никакой ошибки. А что касается оператора, то он  выдает системе информацию для выхода из программы с помощью `exit(1)`, если  условие выполняется, а если нет, т. е.  `n` находится в правильном диапазоне, возвращается  данный элемент массива `arr[n]`. А вместо `cout` элегантнее использовать `cerr` для сообшения об ошибках, поскольку после такого вывода у вас других выводов не будет

Answer (score 0):

```
class safearray // класс такой класс
{ // открывающая скобка. фигурная.
    private: // атрибут доступа
    int arr[LIMIT]; // массив целых знаковых размером LIMIT
    public: // атрибут доступа
    int& operator[](int n) // перегрузка оператора
    { // открывающая скобка. фигурная.
        if (n < 0 || n >= LIMIT) // если n меньше нуля; 
        //или больше или равно LIMIT - вывести сообщение об ошибке и 
        // завершить программу (руки бы оторвать за такое)
        {
            cout << "\nОшибочный индекс!"; exit(1);
        }
        // вернуть число по индексу n
        return arr[n];
    }
};

int main() // ещё вопросы?
{
    safearay sa1;
    for (int j = 0; j < LIMIT; j++)
        sa1[j] = j * 10;
    for (j = 0; j < LIMIT; j++)
    {
        int temp = sa1[j];
        cout << "Элемент " << j << " равен " << temp << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, вы очень помогли, самый умный Человек на планете(нет).Вы мой вопрос прочитали? Зачем мне ваш комментарий про класс, фигурную скобку? "Руки бы оторвать за такое"- во первых, это пример из книги, во вторых, пишите лучший вариант написания чего-то прямо в ответе, а не комментируйте работу условного оператора!